# How to have a responsive screen in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

There is a `react-native-extended-stylesheet` lib but it doesn't install when installing it gives problems.
Is there a lib or method to make the screen responsive that adjusts the image and text according to the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment as my rep isnt 50 yet, but does this help. this uses viewport width. It listens for the width of the viewport and adjusts the DOM according to your specifications...

If the viewport is less than, or equal to, 700 pixels wide, change the background color to yellow. If it is greater than 700, change it to pink

```
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```